# How to make ComboBox drop-down list be *Narrower* than the ComboBox itself

Tags: delphi, combobox, delphi-10.1-berlin

Is it possible to make a ComboBox Drop-down list be *Narrower* than the Combobox itself?

There are plenty of examples setting the width using
 `SendMessage(Handle, CB_SETDROPPEDWIDTH, 100, 200);`

but the *minimum* value is taken from the combobox itself, regardless of what is specificed here.

All these examples make it bigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the drop-down list is to be painted, a [WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761360(v=vs.85).aspx) message is issued.

By overriding the combobox `WindowProc` it is possible to shrink the drop down list width.

The `WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX` message is detected and since the message supplies the handle of the list window, we can grab the list bounds and call `MoveWindow` with a shrinked width.

```
type
  TMyForm = class(TForm)
    ...
    ComboBox1 : TComboBox;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    ...
  private
    { Private declarations }
    ComboBox1WindowProcORIGINAL : TWndMethod;
    procedure ComboBox1WindowProc(var Message: TMessage);
    ...
  end;

procedure TMyForm.ComboBox1WindowProc(var Message: TMessage);
var
  lbr: TRect;
begin
  //drawing the list box with combobox items
  if Message.Msg = WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX then
  begin
    //list box rectangle
    GetWindowRect(Message.LParam, lbr);
    //Shrink window width
    MoveWindow( Message.LParam,
                lbr.Left,
                lbr.Top,
                50,                  // New width
                lbr.Bottom-lbr.Top,
                false); 
  end;
  ComboBox1WindowProcORIGINAL(Message);  
end;

procedure TMyForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //attach custom WindowProc for ComboBox1
  ComboBox1WindowProcORIGINAL := ComboBox1.WindowProc;
  ComboBox1.WindowProc := ComboBox1WindowProc;
end;
```

[image]
[image]

---

You can make a small hack by creating an interposer class. Either put it in a separate unit and declare it after `vcl.StdCtrls`, or put it in your form unit.

```
type
  TComboBox = class(vcl.StdCtrls.TComboBox)
    private
      FDropDownWidth : Integer;
      function GetDropDownWidth : Integer;
    protected
      procedure WndProc(var Mess: TMessage); override;
    public
      Constructor Create( aOwner: TComponent ); override;
      property DropDownWidth : Integer read GetDropDownWidth write FDropDownWidth;
  end;

constructor TComboBox.Create(aOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  DropDownWidth := -1;  // Default state
end;

function TComboBox.GetDropDownWidth: Integer;
begin
  if FDropDownWidth = -1 then // Just keep a default state
    Result := Self.Width
  else
    Result := FDropDownWidth;
end;

procedure TComboBox.WndProc(var Mess: TMessage);
var
  lbr: TRect;
begin    
  if Mess.Msg = WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX then
  begin
    //list box rectangle
    GetWindowRect(Mess.LParam, lbr);
    //Shrink window width
    MoveWindow( Mess.LParam,
                lbr.Left,
                lbr.Top,
                DropDownWidth,
                lbr.Bottom-lbr.Top,
                false);
  end
  else
  if Mess.Msg = CB_SETDROPPEDWIDTH then
    DropDownWidth := Mess.WParam;

  Inherited WndProc(Mess);
end;
```

Either set the drop-down width with `cb.Perform(CB_SETDROPPEDWIDTH,newWidth,0);` or `cb.DropDownWidth := newWidth;`

Comment: I haven't investigated this more, but in general, I would never personally resize a control from a painting stage message. It asks for an endless loop. But that's my personal opinion, not based on any research.

Comment: @Victoria, no problem with triggering new painting events here. `MoveWindow` redraw is set to false.

Comment: This is the kind of thing that might break in a futue version of Windows (or with different settings).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand, as long as windows needs a brush to paint the background colour and text colour, it will work.