# How to change the position of dropdown list of a combo box?

Tags: delphi, combobox, delphi-2009

I want to change the width of the dropdown list to fit the items text. Doing that, there may be cases when the list expands outside the screen. What I want to do is to move the dropdown list inside the screen to make it visible again.

The problem is described in [this article](https://www.thoughtco.com/sizing-the-combobox-drop-down-width-1058301). But I tried it and it doesn't work. I never receive `WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX` message. I also tried to use `MoveWindow` method with `ComboBox.ListHandle` but the list it's drawn in its default position.

Comment: You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50117711/576719) anwer how to shrink the drop-down width, and adapt for your purpose.

Comment: I don't want to shrink it, I want to change its position.

Comment: I said to adapt it for your purpose. It shows how to receive the `WM_CTCOLORLISTBOX` message and how to use the `MoveWindow` method. What more do you want?

Comment: Oh, sorry ! I did not see it well. Ok, but is it really necessary to hook the WindowProc ? It doesn't work just by using `procedure WMCtlColorListBox(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX` ?

Comment: No, that does not work. Peter Below answered that a [long time ago](http://www.delphigroups.info/2/74/481034.html): *`Look at the source. TCustomCombobox.WndProc does this: 
      WM_CTLCOLORMSGBOX..WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC: 
        begin 
          SetTextColor(WParam, ColorToRGB(Font.Color)); 
          SetBkColor(WParam, ColorToRGB(Brush.Color)); 
          Result := Brush.Handle; 
          Exit; 
        end;  There is no call to inherited, which means the message never reaches 
Dispatch and so your handler is never called. There is probably a reason 
for that but i don't know which.`*

Comment: It works, but if I make the width bigger, when I close the list, that portion it's not repainted...

Comment: And if I move the mouse over that list, everything gets corrupted. Edit: It seems that I must set `True` to `MoveWindow`.

Answer (score 1):

That's how I did to have a ComboBox with auto list width, which does not come out of the screen when dropped down:

```
  TNewComboBox = class(TComboBox)
  private
    FAutoListWidth: Boolean;
  protected
    procedure WndProc(var Msg: TMessage); override;
    procedure DropDown; override;
    procedure SetDropDownCount(const Value: Integer); override;
    procedure CreateWnd; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  published
    property AutoListWidth: Boolean read FAutoListWidth write FAutoListWidth default False;
    property DropDownCount default 20;
  end;

constructor TNewComboBox.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
 inherited;
 FAutoListWidth:= False;
 DropDownCount:= 20;
end;

procedure TNewComboBox.CreateWnd;
begin
 if HandleAllocated then SetDropDownCount(DropDownCount);
end;

procedure TNewComboBox.WndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
var ListR, ComboR: TRect;
    Wdt, Hgt: Integer;
begin
 if (Msg.Msg = WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX) then begin
  GetWindowRect(Handle, ComboR);
  GetWindowRect(Msg.LParam, ListR);
  Wdt:= ListR.Right - ListR.Left;
  Hgt:= ListR.Bottom - ListR.Top;
  if ListR.Right > (Screen.Width - 5) then ListR.Left:= Screen.Width - 5 - Wdt
   else if ListR.Left < 5 then ListR.Left:= 5;
  MoveWindow(Msg.LParam, ListR.Left, ListR.Top, Wdt, Hgt, True);
 end;
 inherited WndProc(Msg);
end;

procedure TNewComboBox.DropDown;
var I, item_width, max_width: Integer;
begin
 max_width:= 0;
 if FAutoListWidth then begin
  for I:= 0 to Items.Count -1 do begin
   item_width:= Canvas.TextWidth(Items[I]) + 10;
   if item_width > max_width then max_width:= item_width;
  end;
  if DropDownCount < Items.Count then
   max_width:= max_width + GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVSCROLL);
 end;
 SendMessage(Handle, CB_SETDROPPEDWIDTH, max_width, 0);
 inherited;
end;

procedure TNewComboBox.SetDropDownCount(const Value: Integer);
begin
 inherited;
 if HandleAllocated then
  SendMessage(Handle, CB_SETMINVISIBLE, WPARAM(Value), 0);
end;
```

Thanks for the tips !

Answer (score 0):

You could use GetComboBoxInfo:

```
const
    WM_AFTER_DROPDOWN = WM_USER + 123;

type
TForm2 = class(TForm)
    ComboBox1: TComboBox;
    procedure ComboBox1DropDown(Sender: TObject);
private
    procedure WMAfterDropDown(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_AFTER_DROPDOWN;
    procedure MoveListWindow;
end;

var
Form2: TForm2;

implementation

procedure TForm2.MoveListWindow;
var
    cbi: TComboBoxInfo;
    r: TRect;
begin
    cbi.cbSize := SizeOf(cbi);
    GetComboBoxInfo(Combobox1.Handle, cbi);
    GetWindowRect(cbi.hwndList, r);
    MoveWindow(cbi.hwndList, 0, 0, r.Width, r.Height, true);
end;

procedure TForm2.WMAfterDropDown(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
    MoveListWindow;
end;

procedure TForm2.ComboBox1DropDown(Sender: TObject);
begin
    PostMessage(Handle, WM_AFTER_DROPDOWN, 0, 0);
end;
```

Comment: `OnDropDown`, but it's not working. I think the handle it's wrong.

Comment: I have edited my answer, you should use PostMessage to let the list window to be created first

Comment: It's still not working. The list is moved succesfully, but the animation appers in its default pozition.